# backbone js: collection event function options index undefined

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I tried to get index value for the model. but its returning undefined value. how to get index value once an event is triggered.

```
var Test=new Backbone.Collection();

Test.add({name:'gowtham',age:20});
Test.add([{name:'eswara',age:25},

{name:'sakthi',age:20}]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(Test));

Test.remove(Test.at(1));
console.log(JSON.stringify(Test));

Test.on('add',function(model, col, options) {
    console.log('added ' +model.get('name')+'at index '+ options.index);
});
Test.add({name:'ganesh',age:22});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example i do not see any try to output index of a model

```
Test.on('add',function(model, col, options) {
    console.log('added ' +model.get('name')+'at index '+ `options.index);`
});
```

maybe its just a typo.

By default backbone `add` event callback has this three arguments: `model`, `collection` and `options` and there is no index, so you have to get it by yourself

I am putting here snippet about how to get index of added model
and how to add model at certain index

you still can check for additional information here: [backbonejs.org](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection)

```js
let test = new Backbone.Collection([{},{},{}]);

test.on('add', (model, collection) => {
 console.log('index is: ', collection.indexOf(model)) 
});

let model1 = test.add({});
// console: index is: 3

test.add({}, { at:0 });
// console: index is: 0

console.log('model new index: ' + test.indexOf(model1))
// console: model new index:  4
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now am edited the question in one example they are getting options.index's value

Comment: options.index filled if you pass `at` value to the options